# Concatenar variável com array em PHP

Tags: php, array, variáveis, concatenação-de-string

Tenho uma variável `nome`, e um `array`.

Como pôr essa variável no `array`? Exemplo:

```
['dia'].$nome;
```

Quando faço isso, retorna erro.

O `array` `dia` contém uma `string`, como por exemplo: `"Domingo"`, e `nome` o valor `1`.

Código: 
 $nome = '-bla';
 $teste. $_FILES['arquivo'].= $nome;

o array retorna : Array ( [name] => A91126.pdf [type] => application/pdf [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3BA0.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 21710 )

Comment: Coloque mais detalhes na sua pergunta, em especial o motivo para querer fazer isso.

Comment: Primeiro precisamos entender o que deseja, a pergunta está muito vaga. Antes de tudo precisa saber com clareza o que deseja fazer e comunicar isto para depois vermos como fazer isso em código. De fato este código não faz sentido e nem conseguimos tentar adivinhar a intenção por ele.

Comment: Simples quero somar um valor de uma variavel no array. Prem concatenando o array mais a variavel da erro

Comment: Deu para entender que você não consegue atribuir um valor a um array, porem você não explicou de forma clara o objetivo deste código, ou você quer apenas saber como atribuir o valor de uma variável qualquer a um índice de um array?

Comment: Isso mesmo gostaria de imprimir o o que tem no array junto com a variavel

Comment: Caro colega, @Inicianteee. Faça um breve [tour pela comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender algumas funcionalidades. Repare que fiz uma edição na sua pergunta formatando o código e etc, logo você fez uma edição que, além de adicionar conteúdo - que é super bem-vindo -, quebrou parte da formatação que fiz. Dá só uma olhada [nessas revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/358281/revisions). Abração! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Para adicionar ao array você informa a chave e simplesmente atribui a sua variável:

`$dias['dia'] = $nome;`

Mas se você já tem um valor dentro e deseja apenas concatenar com o conteúdo já existente você utiliza:

`$dias['dia'] .= $nome;`

Exemplo:
Temos o seguinte array

```
$dias = array(
    'dia' => 'Segunda'
);
```

Ao exibir ele estará assim:

```
    Array
(
    [dia] => Segunda
)
```

Queremos adicionar o '-feira' no final do dia, logo:

```
   $nome = '-feira';    

   $dias['dia'] .= $nome;
```

Irá exibir assim:

```
Array
(
    [dia] => Segunda-feira
)
```

Se o exemplo ficou fácil demais ou não atendeu sua dúvida só comentar que deixo um outro código.

Comment: Ele da o seguinte erro :  Notice: Array to string conversion. Nã teria que converter a variavel em array?

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que você está executando? Escreve o array que fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Sim, agora mesmo

Answer (score -3):

Array origial $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

$_FILES['arquivo']['name'] = "teste";

A saida fica o nome teste como eu queria, bem mais simples e atendeu